# Spring MVC - How to pass HashMap in Request Mapping

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC with RESTFullWebService.

Code Snippet from my client program

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String startProcessURL = "http://"+hostAddress+":"+portNumber+"/jBPMSpring/process/startProcess/"+processId
```

Above code is working fine, When I use RequestMapping.GET method.

From my client program, I need to pass HashMap in Request Mapping (POST).

What changes, I need to do to pass HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, postForLocation or [postForObject](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForLocation%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

After initalizing you can just wrap your hashmap in a class :

```
String result = rest.postForObject("http://whatever.com/whenever/", yourClass, String.class,);
```