# Client Server Communication in REST: Using RestTemplate: Unable to send data to Server side

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, client-server, resttemplate

I am trying to setup a Client-Server communication in REST, Spring.

In the client side I have the code:

```
rresult = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/SpringMVCMerchant/movieTheater.htm", ResponseText.class, variable);
```

The variable above is a HashMap. I want this value variable to be transferred to the server side code. My server side code is:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/movieTheater", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseText getCustomerInput(Map<String, Double> input) {
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    ResponseText result = new ResponseText();
    if(transactionService.addTransaction(input))
        result.setMessage(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.getStatus());
    else
        result.setMessage(ResponseStatus.FAILED.getStatus());
    return result;
}
```

In this side I am expecting Map input will receive the value of Map variable. But, this is not happening. I don't want to send the value as a url parameter. Can you please tell me how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a HTTP Get request you could do a HTTP POST request.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15944890/2179109

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried using POST. I am getting the same 406 error.